# I can't get the selected list items if the page is published

Tags: jslink, jsom

I can't get the array of the selected items on a published page. I used `SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems()`. It all works if the page is checked out, but it returns nothing if the page is published.

For the record I want to call a service that needs the list ID and selected item ID.

Note: I have 3 XSLTListView webparts on the same page.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same weired (as I thought) problem. On published pages you should use

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ListOperation', onSharePointReadyFunc);
```

to execute your script.

SharePoint loads only demanded scripts on published pages.